# Partial regression plots for regularized (L2) linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, regularization, statsmodels, partial-plot

I'm trying to get to grips with multiple linear regression and **partial regression plots**.

The answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125561/what-does-an-added-variable-plot-partial-regression-plot-explain-in-a-multiple) from @Silverfish really helped initially, so I had a go with my own data using Python's [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/):

```
# OLS regression
model = smf.ols('n_taxa ~ tn + toc + p50 + cv + revs_per_yr', data=df).fit()
print model.summary()

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
fig = sm.graphics.plot_partregress_grid(model, fig=fig)
```

The output isn't very interesting, but it seems to make sense: the slopes of the lines on the plots are consistent with the parameter estimates in the summary:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 n_taxa   R-squared:                       0.337
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.239
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     3.456
Date:                Wed, 21 Dec 2016   Prob (F-statistic):             0.0124
Time:                        14:57:31   Log-Likelihood:                -137.72
No. Observations:                  40   AIC:                             287.4
Df Residuals:                      34   BIC:                             297.6
Df Model:                           5                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      32.2439     12.296      2.622      0.013         7.256    57.232
tn             30.6636     20.699      1.481      0.148       -11.401    72.728
toc             0.7627      1.192      0.640      0.526        -1.659     3.184
p50             0.1575      0.103      1.536      0.134        -0.051     0.366
cv             -4.3251      5.240     -0.825      0.415       -14.974     6.324
revs_per_yr    -0.0750      0.060     -1.253      0.219        -0.197     0.047
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.817   Durbin-Watson:                   2.090
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.665   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.253
Skew:                           0.159   Prob(JB):                        0.881
Kurtosis:                       3.225   Cond. No.                     1.99e+03
==============================================================================
```

[image: OLS PRPs]

However, the output also gives a warning about **collinearity**, so I thought I'd have a go with Ridge regression as an alternative. In the example below I've chosen a fairly extreme value for $\alpha$ just to make the difference obvious:

```
# Ridge regression (l1_wt=0)
model = smf.ols('n_taxa ~ tn + toc + p50 + cv + revs_per_yr', 
                data=df).fit_regularized(alpha=10, l1_wt=0)    
print model.summary()

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
fig = sm.graphics.plot_partregress_grid(model, fig=fig)
```

And here's the output:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 n_taxa   R-squared:                      -0.321
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.516
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    -1.654
Date:                Wed, 21 Dec 2016   Prob (F-statistic):               1.00
Time:                        14:53:46   Log-Likelihood:                -151.51
No. Observations:                  40   AIC:                             315.0
Df Residuals:                      34   BIC:                             325.2
Df Model:                           5                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept            0          0        nan        nan             0         0
tn                   0          0        nan        nan             0         0
toc                  0          0        nan        nan             0         0
p50             0.1992      0.116      1.711      0.096        -0.037     0.436
cv                   0          0        nan        nan             0         0
revs_per_yr     0.2015      0.017     11.669      0.000         0.166     0.237
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.508   Durbin-Watson:                   1.994
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.776   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.098
Skew:                          -0.103   Prob(JB):                        0.952
Kurtosis:                       3.129   Cond. No.                     1.99e+03
==============================================================================
```

As expected, the summary is different and the parameter estimates have been forced towards zero, but the partial regression plots are ***exactly*** the same as for the OLS version (above). This is confusing, because the parameter estimate for e.g. `revs_per_yr` from the ridge regression is`+0.2015`, whereas the slope on the partial regression plot is negative (as it was in the OLS output).

**Is it possible/meaningful to use partial regression plots with regularzied regression? If not, is there anything similar that I should be using instead?**

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely this is not supported in statsmodels. I think nobody ever tried this before you, and I'm not even sure what the outcome is supposed to be. (That's the statistics question.)

Comment: BTW: If coefficients are penalized to zero, then this is should be L1 penalization and not Ridge (L2).

Comment: You're right about the coefficients - my code has `l1_wt=0`, but the actual syntax is `L1_wt=0` (capital `L`), so it was ignoring my argument and defaulting to `L1_wt=1`, which is lasso.

Comment: From your first comment, it sounds as though I'm trying to do something unusual/weird, which wasn't my intention. I think I'd better do some more reading! Thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: It might not something weird, and you could open a statsmodels issue for it. The point is that penalized estimation is a recent addition to statsmodels, and we have not yet checked or received enough feedback on the impact on all the possible post-estimation results that are available for plain OLS.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I get any responses here first regarding whether it's a sensible thing to want to do. If it is I'll open an issue. Sounds like you're one of the statsmodels devs? If so, thanks for your efforts - it's a very useful package!