# What is the name of a plot that looks at the effect of ony one variable in a regression model?

Tags: data-visualization, linear-model, terminology, scatterplot, marginal-effect

In short: what is the name of the type of plot below? These seem like standard plots, so I don't want to rename them by accident (I'm giving a presentation on this). The code itself does not matter but I provide it anyway.

Suppose we want a plot that looks only at the effect of one of the factors in a regression model after removing the effects of the other factors. Code for making such plots, in this case for the `iris` data set, is below. I've been calling this a "marginal response" but I'm unsure if that's the right term.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#' Predict the Contribution of a Factor in a Linear Model
#'
#' Returns the predicted contribution of a single factor in a linear model
#'
#' If the factor's value is \eqn{x} and its coefficient in the linear model is
#' \eqn{\beta} this is simply \eqn{\beta x}. However it can be more complicated
#' for, say, quadratic factors
#'
#' @param object \code{\link[stats]{lm}}-class object
#' @param formula A \code{formula} describing the relationship of the factor to
#'                be extracted
#' @param data The data used for fitting \code{object}
#' @return 
#' @examples
#' iris_fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
#' marginal_predict(iris_fit, ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
#' marginal_predict(iris_fit, ~ Sepal.Width, data = with(iris,
#'                                             tibble(Sepal.Width = seq(
#'                                               min(Sepal.Width),
#'                                               max(Sepal.Width), length = 100)
#' )))
marginal_predict <- function(object, formula, data) {
  mat <- model.matrix(formula, data)
  as.vector(mat %*% coef(object)[colnames(mat)])
}

#' Marginalize Contribution in Response Variable
#'
#' Single out the effect of a variable in some observed response variable
#'
#' This function is mostly for plotting the relationship between a factor and
#' some response, but when there are multiple factors explaining the
#' relationship this can be harder to do. The other factors' effect needs to be
#' subtracted. If \eqn{X} is the design matrix of the model and \eqn{p} is a
#' vector of zeros and ones that effectively selects the coefficients relevant
#' to the factor effect being selected, and \eqn{Y}, \eqn{I}, \eqn{\beta}, and
#' \eqn{E} are the response vector, identity matrix, coefficient vector, and
#' error vector respectively, then singling out the effect of the factor is
#' studying
#'
#' \deqn{Y - X(I - p p^\top) \beta = Xp p^\top \beta + E.}
#'
#' This function extracts \eqn{Y - X(I - p p^\top)\beta}.
#'
#' @param object \code{\link[stats]{lm}}-class object
#' @param formula A \code{formula} describing the relationship of the factor to
#'                be extracted
#' @return Response vector after removing the effect of other factors not being
#'         considered
#' @examples
#' iris_fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
#' marginal_response(iris_fit, ~ Sepal.Width)
marginal_response <- function(object, formula) {
  vars <- attr(terms(formula), "term.labels")
  if (attr(terms(formula), "intercept")) {
    vars <- c("(Intercept)", vars)
  }
  response_position <- 1
  response <- object$model[[response_position]]
  model_mat <- model.matrix(object)
  excluded_vars <- !(colnames(model_mat) %in% vars)
  
  as.vector(response - model_mat[, excluded_vars, drop = FALSE] %*%
            coef(object)[excluded_vars])
}

#' Create Data Frames for Plotting Marginal Effects
#'
#' Takes data and a set of candidate points and returns a list with two data
#' frames ready for plotting with \code{\link[ggplot2]{ggplot}}
#'
#' This provides a much easier way to provide the capability provided by
#' \code{\link{marginal_response}} and \code{\link{marginal_predict}} as the
#' data frames generated are ready for plotting since they include the factor's
#' values.
#'
#' @param object \code{\link[stats]{lm}}-class object
#' @param formula A \code{formula} describing the relationship of the factor to
#'                be extracted
#' @param data The data used for fitting \code{object}
#' @param factor The factor in the margin (if this function is improved this
#'               variable should be removed)
#' @param newdata New data at which to make predictions
#' @return A list with two elements, \code{marginal_pred} and
#'         \code{marginal_response}, with data frames having a \code{response}
#'         column and columns representing the variables being marginalized
#' @examples
#' iris_fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
#' mr_data_iris <- marginal_response_df(iris_fit, ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris,
#'                      newdata = with(iris, tibble(Sepal.Width = seq(
#'                                               min(Sepal.Width),
#'                                               max(Sepal.Width), length = 100)
#' )))
#' with(mr_data_iris,
#'   ggplot(mapping = aes(y = response, x = Sepal.Width)) +
#'   geom_line(data = marginal_pred) +
#'   geom_point(data = marginal_response))
marginal_response_df <- function(object, formula, data, newdata) {
  reduced_df <- get_all_vars(formula, data = data)
  list(marginal_pred = tibble("response" = marginal_predict(object, formula,
                                                            newdata)) %>%
                         bind_cols(newdata),
       marginal_response = tibble("response" = marginal_response(object,
                                                                 formula)) %>%
                                                 bind_cols(reduced_df))
}

iris_fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
mr_data_iris <- marginal_response_df(iris_fit, ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris,
                     newdata = with(iris, tibble(Sepal.Width = seq(
                                              min(Sepal.Width),
                                              max(Sepal.Width), length = 100)
)))
with(mr_data_iris,
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y = response, x = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line(data = marginal_pred) +
  geom_point(data = marginal_response))
```

[image: Plot of Sepal.Width contribution to regression model]

What would be a better name for this kind of plot that shows the relationship between the factor and the response subtracting all other factors' contributions?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125561/what-does-an-added-variable-plot-partial-regression-plot-explain-in-a-multiple

Comment: @whuber Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider using base R, & 
commenting it extensively, when illustrating posts here with  
R code. Not everyone who will come to this page will be 
familiar with R, & not all of those 
will be able to read tidy-code. This is a Q&A site for 
statistics, not R.